# Did Ilsa Lund love Victor Lazlo?

Tags: plot-explanation, casablanca

In the movie [Casablanca](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0034583/) Though **[Ilsa Lund](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0003051/?ref_=tt_cl_t2)** married **[Victor Lazlo](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0003055/?ref_=tt_cl_t3)**, but she wanted to fly with **[Rick](http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0003050/?ref_=tt_cl_t1)**.

> Ilsa: But what about us?
>   Rick: We'll always have Paris. We didn't
>   have, we, we lost it until you came to Casablanca. We got it back last
>   night.
>   Ilsa: When I said I would never leave you.
>   Rick: And you never
>   will. But I've got a job to do, too. Where I'm going, you can't
>   follow. What I've got to do, you can't be any part of. Ilsa, I'm no
>   good at being noble, but it doesn't take much to see that the problems
>   of three little people don't amount to a hill of beans in this crazy
>   world. Someday you'll understand that.

**Why did she want to fly with Rick? Didn't she love Victor for a moment?**

Comment: Can't she love them both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rick and Ilsa used to be lovers in the past.

> Rick: Of all the gin joints in all the towns in all the world, she walks into mine

and

> Rick: **We'll always have Paris.**  We didn't have, we'd lost it, until you came to Casablanca.  We got it back last night.

Furthermore, Rick was still "carrying the torch" for Ilsa, as he had forbidden Sam (his pianist) to ever play the song "As Time Goes By" - which was song that reminded Rick of Ilsa:

> Ilsa: Play it, Sam.  Play "As Time Goes By"
>
> Sam: Oh, I can't remember it Miss Ilsa.  I'm a bit rusty on it.
>
> Ilsa: I'll hum it for you
>
> (Ilsa begins humming.  Sam begins to play.)
>
> Ilsa: Sing it, Sam.
>
> (Sam begins to sing)
>
> (Rick walks briskly up to the piano)
>
> Rick: Sam, I thought I told you never to play...
>
> (As he sees Ilsa, Rick stops short.  Sam stops playing.)

--

> Why did she want to fly with Rick? Didn't she love Victor for a moment?

So reconnecting with Rick after all these years, and seeing that he still pined for her, awakened old feelings from that past relationship.  She still loves Victor, of course, but love isn't a binary switch that turns off for one person as soon as they meet another.  It's complicated.

In the end, she goes with Victor after all.

Comment: `Rick and Ilsa used to be lovers in the past, before she married Victor.` --- this statement is wrong Ilsa was married even before she met Rick. Thanks btw. Great answer. @Steve-O

Comment: What makes yo say that?  "We'll always have Paris" refers to a time before the movie began, when Rick and Ilsa were together.  It's a common expression (perhaps inspired by this movie) for two people who were lovers in the past to say "we'll always have X" - referring to some vacation they took together, usually to an exotic location, like Paris.

Comment: `Ilsa: [to Rick] He is my husband, and was, even when I knew you in Paris.`  - You didn't year this line at the bazar scene? @Steve-O

Comment: Oh my bad, it's been a while since I watched the movie.